# Truncate trailing commas from each line based on 1st field in a delimited file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I need to removing trailing commas based on the record_type (1st field). Input file has 50 delimiters, I need reduce them based on the record type. IF 1st field is 400, remove last 10 delimiters, if 300 remove 5 delimiters, if 210 remove 2 commas. The pattern of 400, 300 and 210 repeats and the order has to me maintained.

For example:

```
400,"100.00",,,,"31",,,,"510","410","0102","023",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
300,"110","1",,"2016-04-15",,,"52706","TESTFR1","100.00","1.00",,,"N",,,,,,,,,
210,"6876262",,"23 Rue du Roule",,,"PARIS","DF","75001","FR",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

I need the output as

```
400,"100.00",,,,"31",,,,"510","410","0102","023",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
300,"110","1",,"2016-04-15",,,"52706","TESTFR1","100.00","1.00",,,"N",,,,
210,"6876262",,"23 Rue du Roule",,,"PARIS","DF","75001","FR",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

I tried awk and sed but they are truncating the whole file.

Comment: you said `if 200 remove 2 commas` - did you mean if 210 remove 2 commas?

Comment: This seems strange to me. You _don't_ want the same number of fields on all lines?

Answer (score 3):

Sed can meet your requirements.  This will match the desired beginning of the string, and then remove the desired number of commas from the end.

```
sed -e '/^400/ s/,\{10\}$//' -e '/^300/ s/,\{5\}$//' -e '/^210/ s/,\{2\}$//'
```

Answer (score 1):

AWK approach. We define `trunk` function to print a sub-string of the whole line, from index 0 to index length - n characters. The rest is simply pattern matching, and calling `trunk` function with appropriate number of characters to be removed.

As one liner :

```
$ awk -F ',' 'function trunk(n){print substr($0,0,length($0)-n)}; $1==400{trunk(10)};$1==300{trunk(5)};$1==210{trunk(2)} ' input.txt
```

From a script this would be like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS="," };

function trunk(n){
    print substr($0,0,length($0)-n)
}; 

$1==400{ trunk(10)};
$1==300{trunk(5)};
$1==210{trunk(2)};
```

And here it is in action:

```
$ ./trunk_lines.awk input.txt                                                                                            
400,"100.00",,,,"31",,,,"510","410","0102","023",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
300,"110","1",,"2016-04-15",,,"52706","TESTFR1","100.00","1.00",,,"N",,,,
210,"6876262",,"23 Rue du Roule",,,"PARIS","DF","75001","FR",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that the trailing fields are empty (or if you want to delete them as well)

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '$1=="400"{NF-=10} $1=="300"{NF-=5} $1=="210"{NF-=2} 1' file
```

or if you want to be clever (which can be both a good and bad thing)

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, 'BEGIN{x[400]=10;x[300]=5;x[210]=2} {NF-=x[$1]} 1' file
```

Comment: Trailing fields are mostly empty..I just had to match the number of delimiters for the other application to accept my file.